# ActiveMQ Artemis STOMP NACK incompatible

Tags: activemq-artemis, stomp

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.31.2 and the STOMP protocol. I want to have messages redelivered or placed on a DLQ, but [the source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-protocols/artemis-stomp-protocol/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/protocol/stomp/v11/StompFrameHandlerV11.java) of ActiveMQ Artemis shows:

```java
@Override
public StompFrame onNack(StompFrame request) {
   //this eventually means discard the message (it never be redelivered again).
   //we can consider supporting redeliver to a different sub.
   return onAck(request);
}
```

What solution would be an alternative to NACK? I searched and viewed the official source code.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you set the `ack` header on your `SUBSCRIBE` frames to `client-individual` which means you can acknowledge any message you like and then when you close your connection any messages which you *didn't* acknowledge will be placed back on the queue for delivery to other consumers.

Comment: I used a prefetchSize to handle approximately 5 messages concurrently. Closing the connection will discard any remaining messages.

Comment: Perhaps each concurrent consumer should have their own connection.